# Should I add only one either "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1" or "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1" to build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio

In order to use `androidx.preference`, I should add the dependencies to build.gradle

*Image A* is from https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference

1: I don't think it's good, I should use *Code A1* or *Code A2*, right?

2: And more, *Image B* is from  https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready
I think it's good. I should use *Code B1* if my project mix java and kotlin, I should use *Code B2* if my project only write by Kotlin, right?

**Image A**

[image]

**Code A1**

```
dependencies {
    def preference_version = "1.1.1"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$preference_version"   
}
```

**Code A2**

```
dependencies {
    def preference_version = "1.1.1" 
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:$preference_version"
}
```

**Image B**
[image]

**Code B1**

```
dependencies {
    def billing_version = "3.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version'
}
```

**Code B2**

```
dependencies {
    def billing_version = "3.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:$billing_version'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *KTX* artifacts usually contain *Kotlin* extensions to the original artifact.

This means that `androidx.preference:preference-ktx` already depends on `androidx.preference:preference` and you don't need to include both separately.

If you don't intend to use the *Kotlin* extensions, you don't need to use the `androidx.preference:preference-ktx` artifact. You'll find the documentation for these *Kotlin* extensions on [developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/preference/package-summary#extension-functions-summary).

So a rule of thumb: use the *KTX* artifact whenever you use *Kotlin* in your project.